# Specflow - Scenario Outline tests are being ignored

Tags: c#, msbuild, automated-tests, nunit, specflow

I'm developing test automation with Selenium and Specflow, but when I try to run my Scenario Outline, it is *completely ignored.* 

I've already tried to debug it and **none** of the steps is executed and I have no idea why. 

Common Scenarios work just fine.

I'm using .NET Core 2.2 in Visual Studio Code. My current test Runner is NUnit version 3.12.0 and and my Specflow version is 3.0.225.
Regular Scenarios haven't shown any problem like this.

```
@FilterScenario
Scenario Outline: Validating filter box and grid results
    Given I accessed the screen
    And the filter box is on
    When I select the groups <TypeGroup1>, <TypeGroup2>, <TypeGroup3>
    And select the teams <TypeTeam1>, <TypeTeam2>, <TypeTeam3>
    And click the Apply button
    Then the grid should show me only results that match groups <TypeGroup1>, <TypeGroup2>, <TypeGroup3> and teams <TypeTeam1>, <TypeTeam2>, <TypeTeam3>

    Examples:
    | TypeGroup1 | TypeGroup2 | TypeGroup3 | TypeTeam1  | TypeTeam2  | TypeTeam3  |
    | Type 1     |            |            | Type 1     |            |            | 
    | Type 1     | Type 2     | Type 3     | Type 1     | Type 2     | Type 3     |
    |            |            |            | Type 1     |            |            |
```

Packages included on my project:

```
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="nunit" Version="3.12.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.13.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.Support" Version="3.141.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver" Version="3.141.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Specflow" Version="3.0.225" />
    <PackageReference Include="Specflow.Assist.Dynamic" Version="1.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Specflow.NUnit" Version="3.0.225" />
    <PackageReference Include="SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation" Version="3.0.225" />
```

Comment: Which unit test provider are you using? Which version of the SpecFlow NuGet package are you using? If you change a regular `Scenario` do you see that change when running that test?

Comment: I'm using NUnit version 3.12.0, and my Specflow version is 3.0.225. And yes I do, regular Scenarios haven't shown any problem like this.

Comment: Can you add this info to your question? It is too easily missed when put in comments.

Comment: Which NuGet packages do you have installed?

Comment: Sure! Just did it :) I added the packages to the question also.

Comment: Are there regular scenarios that work inside the *same* feature file as the scenario outline?

Comment: Yup, there are 9 regular scenarios that work just fine inside the same feature file.

Comment: Does the feature.cs for that scenario outline file get updated when you build the solution?

Comment: Yes! It does. :)

Comment: Can you try running the test from the command line? Or at least running all the scenarios in that feature file from the command line using something like vstest.console.exe?

Comment: Perhaps try single quotes as per hint in https://specflow.org/documentation/Using-Gherkin-Language-in-SpecFlow/: Hint: In certain cases, when generating method names using the regular expression method, SpecFlow is unable to generate the correct parameter signatures for unit test logic methods without a little help. Placing single quotation marks (') around placeholders (eg. '<placeholder>')improves SpecFlow's ability to parse the scenario outline and generate more accurate regular expressions and test method signatures.

Comment: Hi, I executed the test project from the command line after adding the single quotation marks around placeholders and the scenario outline hasn't been ignored this time! But it's still ignored when executing from the test explorer.

Answer (score 0):

There are problems in your feature file.

```
@FilterScenario
Scenario Outline: Validating filter box and grid results
    Given I accessed the screen
    And the filter box is on
    When I select the groups '<TypeGroup1>', '<TypeGroup2>', '<TypeGroup3>'
    And select the teams '<TypeTeam1>', '<TypeTeam2>', '<TypeTeam3>'
    And click the Apply button
    Then the grid should show me only results that match groups '<TypeGroup1>', '<TypeGroup2>', '<TypeGroup3>' and teams '<TypeTeam1>', '<TypeTeam2>', '<TypeTeam3>'

    Examples:
    | TypeGroup1 | TypeGroup2 | TypeGroup3 | TypeTeam1  | TypeTeam2  | TypeTeam3  |
    | Type 1     |            |            | Type 1     |            |            | 
    | Type 1     | Type 2     | Type 3     | Type 1     | Type 2     | Type 3     |
    |            |            |            | Type 1     |            |            |
```

Regenerate the stepdefs and try again